# .Net Maui Release Build is not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, maui

When I invoke TryToLogin by clicking "Login" button in my .Net Maui Blazor Hybrid App I got unhanced error, I even have try catch block but catch is not calling. This problem only in Android Release Build, In Android Debug build everything works good, wheare problem can be or at least how can I debug Release build?

```
private class LoginService
{
    public async Task<User> TryToGetUser(UsersRepository usersRepository, string login, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var users = await usersRepository.GetAllUsers();
            if (users == null || users.Length == 0) return null;

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                if (user.login == login || user.email == login)
                {
                    var pasHash = password.GetSHA256Hash();
                    if (user.password == pasHash)
                    {
                        return user;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ошибка", $"Ошибка: {ex}", "Ок");
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private async Task TryToLogin()
{

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(login))
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Пожалуйста введите свой логин или email в поле, что бы продолжить", "Ок");
        return;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) || password.Length < Constants.minPassLength)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ошибка", $"Пожалуйста введите свой пароль в поле, что бы продолжить, минимальное количество символов {Constants.minPassLength}", "Ок");
        return;
    }

    isLoading = true;

    LoginService service = new LoginService();

    User currentUser = await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        return await service.TryToGetUser(usersRepository, login, password);
    });

    if (currentUser == null)
    {
        isLoading = false;
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Пользователь с таким логином и паролем не найден, попробуйте проверить регистры", "Ок");
        return;
    }

    userHandler.Save(currentUser);

    await SecureStorage.SetAsync("login", login);
    await SecureStorage.SetAsync("password", password);

    navigationManager.NavigateTo("/home");
}
```

Comment: It is important for **future** readers to not copy-paste this security desaster

Comment: Why you think that my solutuin is "security disaster"? For me it's look ok. I'm newbie to .Maui and web technologies, I'm mostly Unity developer so I never was working with databases, connections to vps and all that stuff before.

Comment: You store hashed passwords in the database ... but you should use salt and more then 10.000 iterations to build the hash. Use [BCrypt.Net Next](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt.Net-Next/) and hash with `BCrypt.EnhancedHashPassword` and verify with `BCrypt.Verify`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

I fixed this problem by disabling TRIMMING and AOT in Project settings, if someone will have same problems you can read about "linker" or something like that